# Thanks giving to all members of this community

Tags: discussion

Since its thanks giving ,just want to take a moment to thank all those people who are connected with this community and help by posting questions ,answering or monitoring .

Looks like we are doing fairly good with some great questions from time to time .I see lot of folks from salesforce helping us and special thanks to all people who work for salesforce and listen our concerns .

Comment: Thank you all!  :-)

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 6):

I've been a member of this community for a few years now. It is my single most reliable go-to community for complex technical questions. Forget SF Premiere support - the top posters on this site probably know more about SF architecture than SF's own dev team!

I started here as an apex/VF newbie. I am just now reaching a level of knowledge where I can start giving back and answering questions myself. What I love about this site is that it's not just about helping people with one-offs, its about establishing a base of knowledge that can be referred to indefinitely. It has made me be more careful about what kinds of questions I ask, and how I phrase them to make them the most helpful for others with similar issues.

Thanks to all of you posters who go through unanswered questions and spend hours helping the rest of us out. (Mohith you are one of them!)